# Not entering onCharacteristicRead or onCharacteristicChanged

Tags: java, android, bluetooth-lowenergy

As the title states my code seems to get stuck after `onServicesDiscovered`, the only reason i know this is that I have Log messages denoting so. Can anyone reveal what is wrong with my code? I can connect to my device but I am not receiving the data from it. I know its on my apps side because ive used the adafruit bluefruit app and the nRF app and they both receive the data.

```
public void onConnectionStateChange(BluetoothGatt gatt, int status, int newState) {
            super.onConnectionStateChange(gatt, status, newState);

            Log.i("onConnectionStateChange", "State Changed from: " + status + " to " + newState);
            gatt.discoverServices();

            // seems to connect but if statements dont work?

//            if (newState == BluetoothProfile.STATE_CONNECTED){ // 2
//                Toast.makeText(BluetoothDiscovery.this, "Attempting service discovery", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
//                Log.i("onConnectionStateChange", "Attempting service discovery: " + mGatt.discoverServices());
////                mGatt.discoverServices();
//            } else if (newState == BluetoothProfile.STATE_DISCONNECTED){ // 0
//                Toast.makeText(BluetoothDiscovery.this, "Connection has been terminated", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
//            } else if (newState == BluetoothProfile.STATE_CONNECTING) { // 1
//                Log.i("Welp", "IM GIVIN ER ALL SHES GOT CAPN");
//            } else if (newState == BluetoothProfile.STATE_DISCONNECTING) { // 3
//                Log.i("Welp", "HOW DID WE GET HERE");
//            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onServicesDiscovered(BluetoothGatt gatt, int status){
            super.onServicesDiscovered(gatt, status);

            Log.i("onServicesDiscovered", "Hey, we found a service");

            List<BluetoothGattService> services = gatt.getServices();
            Log.i("SERVICE", "Services: " + services.toString());


            //BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic = services.get(4).getCharacteristics().get(0);
            BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic = gatt.getService(baseUUID).getCharacteristic(rxUUID);


            if (characteristic != null){
                gatt.setCharacteristicNotification(characteristic, true);
            }


            List<BluetoothGattDescriptor> describeMe = characteristic.getDescriptors();
            Log.i("DESCRIPTORS", "Descriptors: " + describeMe.toString());
            Log.i("DESCRIPTORS", "Descriptors: " + describeMe.get(1).getUuid().toString());


            BluetoothGattDescriptor descriptor = characteristic.getDescriptor(describeMe.get(1).getUuid());
            descriptor.setValue(BluetoothGattDescriptor.ENABLE_NOTIFICATION_VALUE);
            gatt.writeDescriptor(descriptor);

            Log.i("ByeSERVICESDISCOVERED", "that");
        }
```

Comment: For anyone looking this up in the future: If you receive a message similar to `D/BluetoothGatt: onConnectionUpdated() - Device=xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx interval=6 latency=0 timeout=500 status=0` you are connecting to the device but not "enough" to recieve info. For me it turned out i had to click the device to connect to a second time to actually recieve the data. I dont know why yet.